# Behat + BrowserStack

Tags: php, silverstripe, behat, browserstack

I am looking to integrate Behat and BrowserStack. I got the basic functionality set up but I want to enable local tunnling. I have downloaded the required jar to do that. The problem comes when I want to set the "browserstack_tunnel" param.

In the MinkExtenstion/Services/Extention.php I added the following keys to the seliuem2 profile.

```
booleanNode('browserstack-tunnel')->end()->
booleanNode('browserstack-debug')->end()->
```

This is my behat.yml :

```
default:
 filters:
   tags: "~@todo"
 formatter:
   name: pretty
 parameters:
   snippets: false

extensions:

SilverStripe\BehatExtension\MinkExtension:
  # Adjust "base_url" to your own website URL.
  # Can be set via environment variables or _ss_environment.php/$_FILE_TO_URL_MAPPING as well.
  # 
  # base_url:  http://localhost/

  # TODO Dynamically set through LocatorProcessor
  files_path: %behat.paths.base%/framework/tests/behat/features/files/
  default_session: selenium2
  javascript_session: selenium2
  goutte: ~
  selenium2:
browserstack:
  extensions:
    SilverStripe\BehatExtension\MinkExtension:
      selenium2:
        browser: firefox
        # Add your own username and API token here
        wd_host: http://<username>:<key>@hub.browserstack.com/wd/hub
        browserstack-tunnel: true

    SilverStripe\BehatExtension\Extension: ~
```

Answer (score 2):

To enable tunnel while testing on BrowserStack, you need to pass browserstack.tunnel capability as true in your list of capabilities. Can you please modify the capabilities in behat.yml as show below:

```
    default:
      path: %paths.base%/features
      context: Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext   extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
      selenium2:
        wd_host: http://<USERNAME>:<KEY>@hub.browserstack.com/wd/hub
        capabilities: 
            browser: chrome
            browser_version: 29.0
            os: Windows
            os_version: 29.0
            browserstack.tunnel: true
```

Further there is some information regarding integrating Behat with BrowserStack in the following repository: https://github.com/browserstack/automate-php-samples.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a problem with the Mink Extension and requires you to pull in this [PR](https://github.com/Behat/MinkExtension/pull/114#issuecomment-29318348). If you don't know how. See this https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally

After pulling this pull request see the comments and add to your behat.yml file